# Wait for evaluated attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS 1.0.8

I have created a directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope,element,attrs)

        console.log(attrs.index); // returns undefined

        scope.saveChange = function(){
            console.log(attrs.index); returns correct value

        };
    }
  }
});
```

Example of an element using that directive:

```
 <!-- part of ngRepeat section -->
<input myDirective index="{{$index}}" type="text">
```

Why is it, that when my linking function is invoked, `console.log(attrs.index)` will return undefined, but if i fire `scope.saveChange()`, the correct value is delivered?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? I *think* this was a problem in earlier versions of the 1.0.x line, and is corrected in more recent versions. Can you try a more recent one, if this is the case?

Comment: Thank you.
However, i am using the latest stable release, 1.0.8

Comment: Just for the sake of completenes, can you try the latest version of 1.1.x or even 1.2?

Comment: one way is wrap in $timeout...and inject $timeout in directive. It has to do with digest cycle of ng-repeat not finsihed when link fires. $timeout pushes to end of stack.Another is use attrs.$observe and fire your code when the attribute is defined

Comment: @charlietfl
I am no big fan of such dirty hacks, it would not only cause a performance lack but i can also never be sure what amount of time would be enough to wait

Comment: no way around it. Pick one. The elemnt has to exist for it to have attributes

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos
done, same result

Comment: i would go with the $timeout method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in earlier versions interpolated attributes were not initialized before directive linking. This was changed in 1.1.3 according to the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

From the 1.0.8 documentation:

> The Attributes object - passed as a parameter in the link() or
>   compile() functions - is a way of accessing:
>
> - *observing interpolated attributes*: Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}").
>     Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily
>     get the actual value because during the linking phase the
>     interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this
>     time set to undefined.

Example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      attrs.$observe('index', function(val) {
        console.log(attrs.index);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Plunker with 1.0.8 and `$observe`: http://plnkr.co/edit/WP8eSS?p=preview

Plunker with 1.1.3 and no `$observe`: http://plnkr.co/edit/XUG5bI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's because `console.log(attrs.index);` is in a different scope. You will often find, for example, that you need to use `this.field` on the template instead of just `field`.

Comment: I don't think so, to me it looks like the expression just hasn't been evaluated when i log it. I think that this is proofed by trying the same thing with a primitive value instead of an expression, both will return the correct value.

Comment: Could be, it's just that I had a similar problem with the loop:
`<div ng-repeat='rule in rules'>`
Even if my life depended on it I couldn't do:
`<button type="submit" ng-click="delete_rule(rule.id)"></button>`
But I could do:
`<button type="submit" ng-click="delete_rule(this.rule)"></button>`